# 403 forbidden when serving static files using nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-22.04

Trying to set up a distribution of stytic files with the simplest configuration.

The root directory contains a folder `static` include just styles.css file

```
pwd 

home/ubuntu/static
```

Create new nginx configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/static
```

with body

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 18.198.37.76;

    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/static;
    }
}
```

creating a link from it to the sites-enabled directory

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/static /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

add permission

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ubuntu/static
```

Go to `http://18.198.37.76/styles.css`  and get `403 Forbidden`

nginx log

```
2023/03/02 10:35:01 [error] 16726#16726: *12 open() "/home/ubuntu/static/styles.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 79.184.238.222, server: 18.198.37.76, request: "GET /styles.css HTTP/1.1", host: "18.198.37.76
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this. Firstly I would advice you to walk through this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cd90d1ed3c462fe3bddd11bf8953a896). Maybe you won't need all steps, but do those you need.

Secondly chmod was the right idea, but you need to give the proper user acces, in this case the client. You can do this as such:

```
ps –ef | grep –i nginx
```

will give you the client profile name (probably www-data) next you can

```
chown -R www-data:www-data * (or the client profile which appears for you)
chmod 755 /var/lib/nginx/
```

[This](https://www.educba.com/nginx-forbidden/) can also be a good read if you encounter more issues.

p.s. this is an ubuntu question (as I can see from your commands) so you might be better of asking Ubuntu questions in the future at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) which is also a stack overflow owned website,

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help